# How to Countif from a range while extracting date from text (number of upcoming tasks)

Tags: excel-formula

I want to count the number of times a task needs to occur within 14 days (today is 9/1). But I need to extract the date from strings of text. The formula below returns a spill error instead of one overall count.

Id also like to filter for just selected items (ex: bananas, apples, oranges). When i add that test it says all results are true.

I have conditionally formatted each cell's font to be red when the test is met but I can't count using conditional formatting. I also tried a user defined function in VBA but that can't use conditional formatting either.

**=IF(OR(A5:A22="Bananas",A5:A22="Oranges",A5:A22="Apples"),(COUNTIF(B5:B22,(TODAY()-RIGHT(B5:B22,LEN(B5:B22)-FIND(" ",B5:B22)-0))<-14))**

[sample layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBPsR.png)

[with corrections in comments.. still not complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ0by.png)

Comment: First, lock those cells range, as the formula goes down your sheet, the range may adjust and mess with the results. Next use` Countifs` instead of nesting an Or statement inside of an IF then doing a countif. This allows you to have multiple criteria to count by and is much more straightforward of a formula.

Comment: =COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$22,OR($A$5:$A$22="Oranges",$A$5:$A$22="Bananas",$A$5:$A$22="Apples"),$B$5:$B$22,(TODAY()-RIGHT($B$5:$B$22,LEN($B$5:$B$22)-FIND(" ",$B$5:$B$22)-0)>-14))

tried this and it still gives me the spill error and zeroes for every result.

I can separate into two parts but it seems a little messier than i would like

=IF(OR(A5="Apples",A5="Oranges",A5="Bananas"),(TODAY()-RIGHT(B5,LEN(B5)-FIND(" ",B5)-0)>-14))

=COUNTIF(C5:C22,TRUE)

Result 5

Comment: =sum(1*(formula you've given > 0))?

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j99D1zLWpmBQD3q20f?e=ow2ztW) refer:

---

[image: Example application]

```
=SUM(1*(1=--ISNUMBER(MATCH(B3:B11,F3:F4,0)*(TODAY()-RIGHT($C$3:$C$11,LEN($C$3:$C$11)-FIND(" ",$C$3:$C$11)-0)>-14))))
```

---

Notes:

1. Have not paid much attention to the date component as you seem fine with that aspect (to customise illustrative e.g. I've used, replace the last part of equation above i.e. `(9-MID(C3:C11,SEARCH("/",C3:C11)+1,LEN(C3:C11))>=-14)` with the condition you've applied - i.e. `(TODAY()-RIGHT($B$5:$B$22,LEN($B$5:$B$22)-FIND(" ",$B$5:$B$22)-0)>-14)`
2. Suggests equation cell H3 becomes: `SUM(1*(1=--ISNUMBER(MATCH(B3:B11,F3:F4,0)*(TODAY()-RIGHT($C$3:$C$11,LEN($C$3:$C$11)-FIND(" ",$C$3:$C$11)-0)>-14))))` (allowing for different ranges I use for this e.g.)
3. Alternative approach might be wrapping suitable function around the conditional formatting eqn. you provided in Q
4. RE: (pt. 3) - toying with idea of countifs, but personally prefer `sum(1*(binary outcome))` 'wrapper' ☺